# Excel Export button using EPPlus

Tags: excel, vb.net, export, epplus

I developed Excel export button for my .Net application using EPPlus ( its an amazing library it helped me design my template really nice!). my gridview data is exporting to Excel file, the columns are in same order as the Gridview. the only issue is that I have added in the template design three columns so I want to have the flexibility and say e.g. column "First name" in gridview should export into Column "D" in Excel. how can you achieve this???

this is my code so far:

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1

                    dr("column" & i.ToString()) = row.Cells(i).Text

                    dr("column" & i.ToString()) = row.Cells(i).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ")
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to change the header text in excel or start inserting data at column D?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want (up to) 3 columns to the left of your gridview columns.

To do so, just change the start in your For loop from 0 to 3. For instance:

```
For i As Integer = 3 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
```